# How to give dynamic no of PopupMenuItem to the PopupMenuButton with flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, dart, popup

How to set dynamically no of `PopupMenuItem` to the `PopupMenuButton` with index like `ListView.builder()`.

Actually i'm using `FutureBuilder` to get data from the api and in response , 4 items are fetched  means it gives dynamic no of items.
and want to show them into `PopupMenuItem` in list form .
but there is no count constructor in `PopupMenuButton` unlike `ListView.builder()`.

Code:

```
FutureBuilder<CommonModel>(
                future: futureListMaterialStatusCommonModel,
                builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<CommonModel> snapshot ){
                  if(!snapshot.hasData){
                    return Text("loading...");
                  }
                   if(snapshot.hasError){
                    return Text(snapshot.error);
                  }
                 //I tried to get solution by loop before showing items but went wrong
                 for(int i ; i< snapshot.data.content.length; i++){
                    itemList.add(
                      PopupMenuItem(
                        value: snapshot.data.content[i].title,//919876543210,
                        child: Text(
                          snapshot.data.content[0].title,
                          style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }

                 return  PopupMenuButton<String>(
                    itemBuilder: (context) => [
                      PopupMenuItem(
                        value: snapshot.data.content[0].title,
                        child: Text(
                          snapshot.data.content[0].title,
                          style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                        ),
                      ),

                    ],
                    onSelected: (value) { 
                      setState(() {
                        materialStatus = value;
                      });

                    },
                    child: materialStatus==null? Text("Select...", 
                      style: TextStyle(color:Colors.orange),)
                      :Text(materialStatus, 
                      style: TextStyle(color:Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                  );
                } ,
              )
```

Answer (score 6):

Finally I made it.
it was so simple, really so dumb I'm.

```
return  PopupMenuButton<String>(
                   itemBuilder: (context ) => 
                  snapshot.data.content
                     .map((item) => PopupMenuItem<String>(
                           value: item.title,
                           child: Text(
                             item.title,
                           ),
                         ))
                     .toList(),


                   onSelected: (value) { 
                     setState(() {
                       materialStatus = value;
                     });

                   },
                   child: materialStatus ==null? Text("Select...", 
                     style: TextStyle(color:Colors.orange),)
                     :Text(materialStatus, 
                     style: TextStyle(color:Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
                 );
```

Comment: I get an error at itembuilder of the popupmenubutton saying type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<PopupMenuEntry<dynamic>>' using your code

Comment: @Texv can you please show me your code?